# UWP - Print multiple xaml sheets using a single print command

Tags: xaml, printing, uwp

Is there a way to accomplish the above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **PrintHelper** object in **Windows Community Toolkit**, you only have to instantiate the PrintHelper object and call **AddFrameworkElementToPrint** method to add the mutiple XAML controls you want to print.

In addition, when you initialize the object, you need to pass a XAML panel that will be used to host printable control. It needs to be in your visual tree but can be hidden with Opacity = 0, like below. For more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/printhelper).

MainPage.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Canvas x:Name="PrintCanvas" Opacity="0"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">click</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

.cs:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var printHelper = new PrintHelper(PrintCanvas);
    printHelper.AddFrameworkElementToPrint(new BlankPage1());
    printHelper.AddFrameworkElementToPrint(new BlankPage2());
    await printHelper.ShowPrintUIAsync("Title");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I need to print a portion of a page located in subgrid, how do I modify the above code.

Comment: The document mentions controls cannot be linked to a visual tree. It means their parent has to be null. If you want to print the subgrid, you can disconnect it before sending it to print or you can create a new one from scratch. If you don't want to use the above method, you need to implement the printing process manually without using the above Toolkit, I created a simple [sample](https://github.com/wcj233/PrintMutilXaml), you can check it. For more details, you can refer to this [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app) about printing.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I used your sample from GigHub and it works well. But how can we do the same when the app has `WebView` control with a webpage displayed in it?

Comment: @nam You could use [WebViewBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush?view=winrt-19041) to print WebView, create a Rectangle and render the content of webview into the Rectangle, then you could print this Rectangle instead.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I tried your suggestion. It shows the printed PDF with blurred content. I have posted the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62701768/1232087).